# How can I remove stage buttons in JFX

Tags: java, css, jfoenix

I've tried a lot to remove the stage buttons in my JFX project frame. I'm using a decorator to fresh up the design.

[image]

I only want to remove the maximize, resize and minimize buttons. The close button should not be removed. Can you give me a tip, how I can deal with this?

```
JFXDecorator decorator = new JFXDecorator(primaryStage, gridContainer);
```

I've tried this to remove the resizable button this way:

```
primaryStage.setResizable(false);
```

```css
.jfx-decorator{
    -fx-decorator-color: #2196F3;
    -fx-text-fill: black;
    -fx-background-color: transparent;
    -fx-border-color: #2196F3;
}

.jfx-decorator .jfx-decorator-buttons-container{
    -fx-background-color: -fx-decorator-color;
}

.jfx-decorator .resize-border{
    -fx-border-color: #2196F3;
    -fx-border-width: 0 4 4 4;
}
.jfx-decorator .jfx-decorator-buttons{
    -fx-background-color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is actually pretty simple. 
If you take a look into the constructor of the decorator:

`public JFXDecorator(Stage stage, Node node) {
        this(stage, node, true, true, true);
 }`

You can set the three Boolean values to false, which exceeds to the wanted solution.

Comment: Awesome! Helped me a lot. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You have to pass the exact number of arguments.
boolean values are...

1  full screen

2 Maximize/Restore

3 Minimize

```
JFXDecorator decorator = new JFXDecorator(mainStage, root, false, false, false);
```

Comment: That is correct, but I figured that like one and a half month ago out. ;D